# When do we need Tag Dispatching in Template Metaprogramming?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I am new to template metaprogramming and I was watching the [type traits talk part II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiAVWcjIF6o&list=PLWrYNZy3dLbL8cQLDcG03ksolyP6qxuXY&index=1) by Jody Hagins. I wanted to replicate a function overload resolution example to detect whether a given type is constant using the following:

```cpp
namespace detail {
template <typename T>
std::true_type is_const(T const);

template <typename T>
std::false_type is_const(T);
}  // namespace detail

template <typename T>
using is_constant = decltype(detail::is_const(std::declval<T>()));

static_assert(is_constant<int const>::value);
```

The above static assertion produces a compiler error saying call to `is_const` is ambiguous. If I use a `TypeTag` to enclose `T` in my template declarations, things work as expected:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct TypeTag {};

namespace detail {
template <typename T>
std::true_type is_const(TypeTag<T const>);

template <typename T>
std::false_type is_const(TypeTag<T>);
}  // namespace detail

template <typename T>
using is_constant = decltype(detail::is_const(std::declval<TypeTag<T>>()));

static_assert(is_constant<int const>::value);
```

I am confused as to why the first declarations without `TypeTag` encapsulation are ambiguous. My guess is it has something to do with `declval` return type being `T` for `cv-qualified` types but then I do not understand how the second case works.

Is it because in the first case `declval<int const>` has return type **int** but in the second case `declval<TypeTag<int const>>` has return type `TypeTag<int const>` so the compiler picks the first template specialization where `T` is replaced with **int** and the template invocation looks like this:

```cpp
<>
std::true_type is_const<TypeTag<int const>>;
```

If my guess is correct, is there a general practice to use tag dispatching with a `TypeTag` (empty struct template) to guard against `cv-qualified` types?

Comment: is_const(T) and is_const(T const) are the same, hence the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the 1st example does not work is that *top-level* `const` in a function argument is ignored, so `is_const(T)` and `is_const(T const)` are the same function signatures. If `const` is not top-level, function signatures are different, e.g. `is_const(T*)` and `is_const(T* const)` are different.

In your 2nd example, `is_const(TypeTag<T>)` and `is_const(TypeTag<T const>)` are different because `TypeTag<T>` and `TypeTag<T const>` are unrelated types.

However, I don't think that your use of `TypeTag` qualifies as "tag dispatch".